# Redirect every other country code to .com using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a working script however I am unsure how to add another statement to the script where it will redirect any other country code than those specified to the domain website.com:

```
$.getJSON("//geoip.nekudo.com/api?callback=",function(data) {
    if (data.country.code == "DK" && window.location.host != "website.dk") {
      window.location.href = "https://website.dk" + window.location.pathname;
    } else if (data.country.code == "NO" && window.location.host != "website.no") {
      window.location.href = "https://website.no" + window.location.pathname;
    };
});
```

Comment: Would i have to add all the OTHER country codes into an array and compare the data response to that of the array?

Comment: Just add another else statement that redirects to `.com`?

Comment: Yeah, just have a "default" to `.com` with an else clause

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `else` part :

```
$.getJSON("//geoip.nekudo.com/api?callback=",function(data) {
    if (data.country.code == "DK" && window.location.host != "website.dk") {
      window.location.href = "https://website.dk" + window.location.pathname;
    } else if (data.country.code == "NO" && window.location.host != "website.no") {
      window.location.href = "https://website.no" + window.location.pathname;
    } else if (data.country.code != "NO" && data.country.code != "DK") {
      window.location.href = "https://website.com" + window.location.pathname;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
  window.location.href = "https://website.com" + window.location.pathname;
}
```

Comment: Please don't toss out code. Explain why it's appropriate and educate the OP and those who are searching for a similar solution.